# Laravel - Correct way of saving avatars

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I have searched stackoverflow for this question but couldn't find anything definitive.

I am wondering what the correct way of storing avatars is in laravel. Should I use the storage folder which laravel provides itself? Or should I upload user avatars in the public folder? The documentation is not making it any clearer for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would say the public directory as they need to be publicly accessible.

Comment: I would have to disagree with David, dependent on your permission requirements. The moment those files are in your public file, anyone can access them. You won't have control on permissions. I would place them in the storage directory, by using the Laravel helpers. You can then control the access to these avatars.